# Linq2Sql, Joining on possible null fields

Tags: linq-to-sql, join, null

I am trying to do a join that could join on a possible null value.

```
from data in Data
join d1 in Data on new { a = data.pId, b = language } equals new { a = d1.pId, b = d1.language } into j1
from dta1 in j1.DefaultIfEmpty()
join d2 in Data on new { a = data.pId, b = fallback} equals new { a = d2.pId, b = d2.language } into j2
from dta2 in j1.DefaultIfEmpty()
where ((int?)dta1.id ?? dta2.id) == data.Id
select data;
```

The problem here is that pId can be null, and if it is, the join won't match as it compares

```
data.pId = null
```

instead of

```
data.pId is null
```

In a normal where clause I could do object.Equals(data.pId, d1.pId) and it would do a null check, but how can I do this in a join?

Comment: What is this query trying to accomplish?

Comment: In this specific case it is doing a fallback over language on a data table, so there may be data for multiple languages, and it should fall back according to a certain order. This is a simplified version to isolate the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is to convert the null value into some other unused, yet equatable value.

```
join d1 in Data
  on new { a = data.pId ?? -33, b = language }
  equals new { a = d1.pId ?? -33, b = d1.language }
  into j1
```

Comment: That would probably work, but I wonder how it would affect the query plan as I have just realised how badly coalescing can screw up query plans.

Comment: A valid concern, but that concern would apply to any technique to perform this operation (join on value OR null).